# implementing publisher and subscriber functionality using activemq-jms from browser(web-client-application(angularjs or javascript or jsp))

Tags: angularjs, web-applications, spring-boot, activemq-classic, spring-jms

i want to implement an application where i should be able to login as a subscriber and i should be able to see the messages/data coming from publisher which am subscribed to.then i should be able to unsubscribe and subscribe to other publishers if i want to.

using JMS,ActiveMQ,SpringBoot i have created a sample standalone application but from here how to connect and communicate to my web application back and forth.

## Here is my implemented standalone application code

### application.properties

```
spring.jms.pub-sub-domain=true
#spring.jms.template.default-destination=testTopic
```

### Publisher.java

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
@Component
public class Publisher implements CommandLineRunner{
@Autowired
private JmsTemplate jmsTemplate ;
@Autowired
private Topic topic1;
@Autowired
private Topic topic2;

@Override
public void run(String... arg0) throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Thread.sleep(5000); // wait for subscriptions, unless they are durable
    this.jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(this.topic1,"-----> 1st message from publisher -- topic 1");
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    this.jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(this.topic1,"-----> 2nd message from publisher -- topic 1");
    /**
     * for topic2 
     */

 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Thread.sleep(5000); // wait for subscriptions, unless they are durable
         this.jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(this.topic2,"-----> 1st message from publisher -- topic 2");
         Thread.sleep(5000);
         this.jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(this.topic2,"-----> 2nd message from publisher -- topic 2");

}
}
```

### Subscriber.java

```
import org.springframework.jms.annotation.JmsListener;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;


@Component
public class Subscriber {
@JmsListener(destination = "Topic1")
public void listener1(String in) {
    System.out.println("Listener1: " + in);
}

@JmsListener(destination = "Topic1,Topic2")
public void listener2(String in) {
    System.out.println("Listener2: " + in);
}

@JmsListener(destination = "Topic2")
public void listener3(String in) {
    System.out.println("Listener3: " + in+"\n listener 3 is just ");
}
}
```

mainclass : springBootApplication

### PubSubJmsBootApplication.java

```
import javax.jms.Topic;
import org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQTopic;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.jms.annotation.EnableJms;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJms
public class PubSubJmsBootApplication {


    @Bean
    public Topic topic1() {
        return new ActiveMQTopic("Topic1");
    }
    @Bean
    public Topic topic2() {
        return new ActiveMQTopic("Topic2");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(PubSubJmsBootApplication.class, args);
    }



}
```

Comment: You will have to implement a WebSocket solution as well for Browser <-> backend communication. But you need to think it through, ActiveMQ/JMS is only a part of the setup and your milage may vary. Please be more specific in your question what you need help with.

Comment: I guess You could very well use Websocket, which works on publish-subscriber model plus you have readily available frameworks both in server side, spring-boot-websocket and angular-websocket or plain sockjs etc.